# Sitecore Experience Editor not working with ".slick" command

Tags: experience-editor, sxa, javascript

I am using **.slick** command on the javascript for my page carousels.
When I try to edit items in Sitecore Experience Editor(Sitecore 9 with SXA) my Save button is disabled and I am unable to add any new or delete existing fields or components on my page.

I guess there was some existing issue with .slick command in Sitecore 8.1.
Do anyone have any update on this or any resolution to make the experience editor work?
I know SXA have the default carousel but I need my custom carousel with the script to work.

**Note:** Below is the sample of the .js file and there is no issue with the script.

```
$('.promo .carousel').slick({
  speed: 400,
  slidesToShow:
  accessibility: false,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 640,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        centerMode: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Generally speaking, I avoid running this kind of JS in the Experience Editor and either give the users a different view  or make sure the controls render nicely without the JS.

Comment: Like @jammykam wrote - for 100% you have some errors in the browser console.

Comment: The console error I see on this is:-
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined". When I remove the class referring to the .slick method on my cshtml the experience editor starts working. I need to have the class with the .slick functionality as this defines my custom carousel property.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I faced a similar issue with slick and experience editor. Slick by default will assume that all direct children of the carousel div should be slides and since EE injects its own code tags that cause issues. There is an option you can set to limit the children of the carousel with a selector called 'slide'.

Try to set it and test again.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue like while, inserting new **view rendering** on the page, error was same as mentioned above of **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read the property 'substr' of undefined**.

I found one solution and it worked totally for me and that is while you are on edit mode, change your slick property of '**infinite**' to false(as by default the value is set to true) and boom there we go with normal flow as before.

Hope it works for you too :)